# Laravel Policy with repository pattern

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern, policy

I am using a repository pattern in my Laravel application.
My problem is related to duplicate SQL queries while I am dealing with repositories and policies pattern. Here is some example.

```
// My Controller
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->authorize('delete', $this->repository->find($id));
    $this->repository->delete($id);

    return back()->with('success', 'Item has been removed');
}
```

executing the above function will run 2 exact same "select" queries.
First, when getting model for the `authorize` function, and the second one while executing delete function.
here is the definition for this function

```
//repository function
public function delete($id)
{
    return $this->find($id)->delete();
}
```

Please note, that I am aware of why 2 of the same queries are executed. my question is How to avoid that to happen when working with the Policy and Repository pattern?

Shall I pass the model to delete function in my repository, so the repository delete function would be

```
//new delete function i my repository class
public function delete($model)
{
   return $model->delete();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the controller:

```
public function destroy(Link $link)
    {
        $this->authorize('delete', $link);
        $this->repository->delete($link);

        return back()->with('success', 'Item has been removed');
    }
```

Yes, in the delete function of the repository you can directly write $model->delete();
This will reduce you 2 select queries to 1.

Comment: Thank you for replay, would you sugest to use depandancy injection with delete method in controller with repository aproche?  In your scenario I would have to use repository and model